# How to alter a table with a column of varchar datatype to Datetime/ Timestamp

Tags: mysql, database, string, null, mysql-workbench

I tried changing the datatype from Varchar to Datetime, but it keeps on bringing the following error.

> Incorrect datetime value: ' ' for column 'pickup_time' at row 6

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsJBm.png)

I was expecting for the query in the image to work.

Comment: please provide your information in text form, not in images

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To change a type to datetime, all existing values must be able to be cast as datetimes without any error.  Find the values that are not, or update them first using str_to_date if it is simply a matter of changing the format.

If there are blank values, you will need to change them to null first.